# How to stay full screen when trigger upload file?

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

I'm recently use `element.requestFullScreen()` to enter full screen mode from my div. However, in my full screen view there's a button could trigger upload file function.

Is it possible for me to force stay in full screen mode while default select file window pop up?

simple demo in steps with jsfiddle
1. click full screen button to full screen mode
2. click file upload input

https://jsfiddle.net/56yzokra/3/

Thanks for reminding me for a simple demo to make it clear

Comment: please create jsfiddle?

Comment: some working snippet would help us debug your issue

Comment: I don't think it's possible, at least not in all browsers on all platforms. What OS are you on? On macOS Firefox doesn't get out of the fullscreen mode, because they use a windowed version of the file picker. Chrome and Safari on the other end use a filepicker that is attached to the browser's window ,this one will make the page get out of the fullscreen mode. Requesting again the fullscreen mode while the file picker is open will create a kind of a bug, where the document takes the full space of the window, but the window itself is still in windowed mode (not fullscreen).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem today, and my solution (may be not the best) was to triggers the fullscreen mode on the change event on the input file:

```
jQuery('#input[type="file"]').change(function(){
                if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
                      var p = document.getElementById('process_container').requestFullscreen()
                      .then(console.log('full'))
                      .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                      });
                  }
            });
```

When the user selects a file to upload, then the DIV that was on fullscreen at first, is added on fullscreen once again. On my case, the input was on a modal, so the modal keeps open when this happens